# C++ check if a list contains a sublist

Tags: c++

I need a container in which I can check if a sequence of elements are present or not. Same thing as substring matching, just for generic collections. I know it's not hard to write, but if it's implemented in some lib already, I wouldn't bother (maybe Boost has something like this?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any sequence container will do. You just need to use std::search algorithm to do the search of the sublist:

```
vector<int> sequence = ...;
vecter<int> sublist = ...;

vector<int>::iterator pos = std::search(
    sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), 
    sublist.begin(), sublist.end());

if(pos == sequence.end()) 
    // not fount
else 
    // found at pos
```

Comment: oh god how did I miss this one :). Thanks.

Comment: @Tamás: If you think this is the answer to your question, please vote it up ans ACCEPT it by clicking the v-like thing under the answer vote count. Thank you

Comment: @Armen, yeah, it just wouldn't let me to accept it that fast, so I had to wait.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want [`std::search`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/search/)?

Answer (score 0):

The `mismatch` algorithm from STL is pretty much `strcmp` for generic containers.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/mismatch/